# Casper.js download binary doesn't work cross-domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-domain, phantomjs, casperjs

I need to download the image resources using Casper.js. I run into cases when the images are hosted on CDN with different domain name. Below for Twitter.com example and it doesn't work even using **web-security=no**: `casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=no test.js`

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');

casper.start();

casper.thenOpen("https://twitter.com/", function() {
  casper.download("https://abs.twimg.com/a/1369885592/t1/img/front_page/cricket@2x.jpg", "test.jpg");   
});

casper.run(function() {
  casper.exit();
});
```

Can someone help me to work around this issue? Is it possible to use `http request` separately? I could do this and it would work

```
casper.thenOpen("https://abs.twimg.com", function() {
  casper.download("https://abs.twimg.com/a/1369885592/t1/img/front_page/cricket@2x.jpg", "test.jpg");   
});
```

But that is way too much overhead.

UPDATE 1:

I am running phantom.js 1.9.0 and casper.js 1.0.2 on **Windows 7**.

This is the error I got (no file being captured of course):

```
Remote: sendAJAX(): Using HTTP method: 'GET'
Remote: getBinary(): Unfortunately, casperjs cannot make cross domain ajax reque
sts
Remote: getBinary(): Error while fetching https://abs.twimg.com/a/1369885592/t1/
img/front_page/cricket@2x.jpg: Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

Comment: I ran casperjs --web-security=no test.js and works for me. This is my log message ([info] [phantom] Step 2/2 https://twitter.com/ (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Downloaded and saved resource in test.jpg)

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm wondering if it's Windows all along...

Comment: not working for me with web securty=no, even base64encode not working same error, will try different module for nodejs